# Cannot understand why this method is unresolved

Tags: java, spring

I am studying Spring with Spring In Action book, i have the code from the book where it works fine:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {
    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
        );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                    filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }

        model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
        return "design";
    }
}
```

but when i typed it in my IDEA **it says that method filterByType cannot be resolved**, but there is no such problem in the book, and no any comment about this problem. I am new in the Spring, tried google a lot, but couldn't find any information about this problem and it source. Could you help me with this problem, a cannot move further because of it.
[screenshot from IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olU2N.jpg)

Comment: There is no such method "filterByType" in your code. Is it a static import? Is it defined somewhere in your class but you didn't include it in the code you posted?

Comment: You either need to write `filterByType`, or if it is from another class, either static import it or extend your class from it.

Comment: If that's the whole class, where do you think the `filterByType` should be resolved from? It's not in the same class, it's not in `Object` type. Obviously, there's no such problem in the book, because snippets in book are never actually compiled, and everything that's missing is considered an extra non-essential information, that's "somewhere out there".

Comment: check this https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/41750.page

Comment: Hey I have just started to read the same book , but I am getting error with the taco class, with `model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());` and the error is `Taco cannot be resolved to a type` any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like this book just contains an error, it does not list the `filterByType()` method. It's not a Spring method. Here you go:

```
private List<Ingredient> filterByType(List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {

    return ingredients.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Source: [Manning Publications](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/41750.page)

Comment: but where should I put it? In the same class? I am getting exception again at x.getType()

Comment: @Kloody Yes, same class.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not prefer readability:

```
  Arrays.stream(types).forEach(a -> model.addAttribute(a.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), ingredients.stream().filter(i -> a.equals(i.getType())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```